# How have best performance with jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, containers

i'm with some dobuts:

1) how can i take best pratices to have best perfomance with my website in jsp ?

2) how i should use treat request.session.getAttribute() and request.attribute() ?

3) all the data between servlet and jsp should be in request.session.getAttribute ? Or in request.getAttribute ?

i'm asking this cause, after a time of use, my tomcat stops, and i'm working with the same tomcat in another project and this never happens.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't worry about jsp-performance, it's been proven and tested enough already.
2. The session is valid for a user between many requests, the `request.getAttribute` is unique for every new `HTTP` request made to your servlet.
3. Definately put all data you can into each request, meaning you have to use `request.getAttribute`.

If you have problems with your tomcat, I would recommend that you either post your stack-trace or hook up some monitoring tool (like your `IDE debugger` or something like [`jconsole`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html)).

Sessions can be useful too. A session typically contains information about logged in users and their *preferences*. For instance, it can be used to store a *username* or the *theme* to use should such thing be available.

Comment: in my case the user should be logged to do some action, so sessions is more appropriated, right ?

Comment: @Valter, **only** store user data in the session, never store *request-specific* information, such as `submitting a form`, in the session.

Comment: that's ok @Johan i'm not submitting a form in a session =)

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your question are:

> 1) how can i take best pratices to have best perfomance with my website in jsp ?

Rather than coding servlets and jsp pages, you should be using a MVC framework. There are many java MVC frameworks like Spring, Struts, Wicket etc. They will help you in creating a better stable and maintainable application

> 2) how i should use treat request.session.getAttribute() and request.attribute() ?

Where to store the data is your design. If you need a attribute to be accessible in multiple requests, you will have to put it in the session. Whereas if you need a attribute only for 1 or 2 requests, you can do ahead with request. A better management is always provided by the frameworks I mentioned above.

> 3) all the data between servlet and jsp should be in request.session.getAttribute ? Or in
>   request.getAttribute ?

Again, this depends on your application and how long you need the data you are trying to access.

Comment: i need that data to be acess in multiple requests, so session is better, right ?
And thanks by the frameworks, gonna search for it.

Comment: yup.. in that case you should be using session